# xcode c++ project with lua lib got link error

Tags: c++, xcode, lua

First, I create a c++ console project.
  Then, I download the lua5.2.0 from lua.org, then make the lib use [make macosx test] and got the liblua.a.
  Finally, I import the lua src into project and drag the liblua.a in project, write some demo code and compile,but get the link error, I confirm there has no grammar error.

```
Ld /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Products/Debug/LuaAdapter normal x86_64
    cd /Users/luocaixin/Desktop/xcodeWS1/LuaAdapter
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Products/Debug -L/Users/luocaixin/Desktop/xcodeWS1/LuaAdapter/Lua.5.2.0/src -F/Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Intermediates/LuaAdapter.build/Debug/LuaAdapter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LuaAdapter.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libc++ -llua -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Intermediates/LuaAdapter.build/Debug/LuaAdapter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LuaAdapter_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Products/Debug/LuaAdapter

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Intermediates/LuaAdapter.build/Debug/LuaAdapter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/lua.o
    /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Intermediates/LuaAdapter.build/Debug/LuaAdapter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/luac.o
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Intermediates/LuaAdapter.build/Debug/LuaAdapter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/lua.o
    /Users/luocaixin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LuaAdapter-dwqvzxkkhfmcsneiftgqstjfemts/Build/Intermediates/LuaAdapter.build/Debug/LuaAdapter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I want to know what cause this error and how to import lua in xcode c++
project correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the error? It's telling you what's wrong: you have more than one `main` function. You've included two object files that contain a `main` function (lua, luac) and probably have one in your test app, too. You need to leave those files out of your project. They are the reference command line interpreter and compiler, respectively. You don't include them if you're embedding Lua as a library.

Comment: I miss understand the error message.Thanks, the reason is exact as you say